Related list (single) is in card-style?
I’ve noticed that related list (single) on Salesforce Lightning record pages are now displaying in a card-style format instead of the tabular data table format that I recall being available previously. When adding related lists to Lightning record pages, I remember them showing as a data table by default.
Could you confirm if this is a recent change in Salesforce functionality or if there’s a specific configuration required to enable the tabular format again?

this normally depends on the container space where you place the related list component. for larger space, it will render the tabular format but if it is a smaller space then it renders card-style, can you check if this is the case ?
